SSIS File System Task - Problem to rename or move file
I have a process that uses 7-zip to zip a bunch of files from a folder and then places the zip to a folder called "Workfolder" once the zip process is complete.
The next step is to move the file to a folder called "complete". The rename option behaves very strange for me.
If I give the zip file a fairly easy name as in "Workfile.zip" and then use the "rename" option it does in fact move my file from the WorkFolder and assigns a new name to the file once it arrives in the CompleteFolder. The file is also removed from the WorkFolder.
However. My filename is in reality a bit more complex. It includes a timestamp and some static values. The timestamp part of the file is assigned by the system variable "StartTime". The name will be something like "File_20240916_135720.zip".
If I now use the rename option, even though there are no renaming happening, then I will end up having the same file in both the WorkFolder and in the CompleteFolder with the exact same name.
The move option simply doesn't work. No matter how much I try I get "couldn't find part of the path" which is strange since the rename option works.
Any idea what's going on?
